# Get div from other website by PHP script

Tags: php, iframe, render

I have a headbreaking question on one of my projects. I want to render a specifications div from an another website into mines (I've permission).

It concerns the following website: http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_x-4320.php

The div: `<div id="specs-list"></div>`

Now I have the following code:

```
 <?php
function get_content_part($part=null, $website = null) 
{
$website = file_get_contents($website);
$data = str_replace("\n", '', $website);
echo preg_match("/\<div class\=\"'.$specs-list.'\"\>(.*)<\/div\>/",$data,$match);
return $match;
}
?>
```

But because the link is different with every product, I made a custom field within wordpress. The URL renders with the following code:

```
<?php echo(types_render_field("gsmlink", array("alt"=>"gsmlink","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

This renders a completely clean source code, only the text.

Now I seriously have NO idea where I've to put this data so the script knows which URL and which div. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You succeeded in getting the contents of a div on another domain. What is the other thing you are trying to do? What are the URLs you are referring to and "the script"? Properly explaining your problem will increase the chance of good answers.